# Convert an inputstream to a string value in Java Android App

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble with function(s) I'm writing. I'm trying to convert an inputstream to a string value. I've written two functions and I'm attempting to extract the String value but my Log.e response is returning NULL. Below is my syntax. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
public JSONArray GetCityDetails(String StateID) {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    String url = "http://mywebsite.com/getCity.php?StateID="+URLEncoder.encode(StateID);

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

    try{

         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

         HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

         httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


    } catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    if(httpEntity !=null){
        try{

            InputStream entityResponse = httpEntity.getContent();
            // not working
            String entityResponseAfterFunctionCall2 = readFully(entityResponse);
            // not working
            String entityResponseAfterFunctionCall3 = letsDoThisAgain(entityResponse);
            Log.e("Entity Response Dude: ", entityResponseAfterFunctionCall3);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponseAfterFunctionCall3);

        } catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;
}

public String readFully(InputStream entityResponse) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length = 0;
    while ((length = entityResponse.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return baos.toString();
}

public String letsDoThisAgain(InputStream entityResponse){

    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(entityResponse);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    try {
        String read = br.readLine();

        while(read !=null){
            sb.append(read);
            read = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();   
}

}
```

Comment: you can read an inputstream only once unless it is buffered and you can reset it.

Comment: @njzk2   `while(bis.available()> 0){
   while(read !=null){
    sb.append(read);
    read = br.readLine();
   }
   bis.reset();
     }` I put that into my **letsDoThisAgain** and I'm now getting this error **End of input at character 0**

Comment: `reset` works with `mark`, but you need to check `isMarkSupported` first.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(inputStream != null)
        {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            try {

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `readFully` call will use your system's default character encoding to transform byte buffer into String.  This is **NOT** what you want to happen.

You should use explicit character set in `toString` call.  The encoding is usually specified in the HTTP request header.

Here is an example of how to convert a `UTF-8` encoded string

```
return baos.toString( "UTF-8" );
```

Your second problem, is once you've consumed the InputString in `readFully` call, the `letsDoThisAgain` will not have anything to read, because the InputStream will be at the EOF.

Comment: readFully and letsDoThisAgain and two separate functions. They have nothing to do with one another

Comment: I always // readFully or letsDoThisAgain while running the app. Neither function relies on one another. When running the app I at least have one function running but never two at the same time.